# Use zeus with Rails 3 and docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, docker, zeus

We have a Rails 3.2.9 app, and recently switched to Docker in development. By now, I've always used zeus local on my machine to preload my codebase and execute tests with Rspec faster.

But how would you achieve this with docker? When I try to install zeus inside my container with `gem install zeus` and start it with `zeus start` I get

```
Unable to accept socket connection.
It looks like Zeus is already running. If not, remove .zeus.sock and try again.
```

And there is a `.zeus.soc` (notice the missing `k` at the end) left in my filesystem.

Has anybody got this working with Docker?

Comment: I still haven't found a solution to this, anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently zeus is not able to create the .zeus.sock file on the vboxsf filesystem used by VirtualBox for sharing a volume with the host. So a solution is to tell Zeus explicitely to create the file somewhere else by setting the ZEUSSOCK environment variable. This is discussed here: https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/488